# Serious alternatives to Blueprint or 960 Grid if restricted to modern browsers?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-frameworks

The (Rails) application in question is an internal application and the audience uses modern browsers on various operating systems (FireFox 4, Safari 5, Chrome 10 and IE 9). No need to care about all the old browsers.

Are there any serious (upcoming) grid or fluid frameworks you can recommend despite the well-known Blueprint and 960?

Comment: Unless it is a requirement, I might suggest not using one. http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/the-problems-with-using-css-frameworks/

Comment: Define 'serious'. It'd also help us if you mentioned why you might not want to be using BP or 960.

Comment: the link 300baud mentions has a few good points, but doesn't mention any of the benefits of the grid framework either. As always, it depends on the type of project and (usually more important) the entirety of the team build up combined with the development process. I've found a defined grid system can weather the 'agile storm' of constant front end code tweaking better at times.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Well, grid for the sake of a robust cross-browser fundament and rapid development. "Serious" in terms of an active community (and therefore support) over a horizon of a couple of weeks/months. No concerns on Blueprint/960 here. However, I wanted to know if there are alternatives I should review before deciding to go with either Blueprint or 960.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1140px is an interesting one I've been using recently, it's designed to work well on high resolution monitors and degrade nicely on much lower resolution monitors (like phones, tablets, etc). http://cssgrid.net/

Comment: Thank you for sharing! This seems really interesting, I'll take a closer look at the weekend...

Answer (score 0):

One year later: while I really like cssgrid, I find myself more comfortable with Twitters Bootstrap and therefore add this as an answer to my old question :)